# Callback doesn't seem to work in Lambda Node.js function - maybe due to firewall?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

So I'm trying to password-protect a static S3 website using Node.js in a Lambda@Edge function and a CloudFront trigger. I use the `www-authenticate` header to get the user's credentials, decode the resulting authorization header to get the username/password, then call `adminInitiateAuth` (from the aws-sdk) to authenticate with a Cognito user pool.

Here's the actual code:

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const headers = request.headers;

    const body = 'Unauthorized';
    const response = {
        status: '401',
        statusDescription: 'Unauthorized',
        body: body,
        headers: {
            'www-authenticate': [{key: 'WWW-Authenticate', value:'Basic'}]
        },
    };

    if(typeof headers.authorization != 'undefined'){
        var decoded = new Buffer(headers.authorization[0].value.split(" ")[1], "base64").toString();
        console.log("decoded from auth header without basic: " + decoded);
        var arr = decoded.split(":");
        var user = arr[0];
        var pass = arr[1];
        console.log("user: " + user);
        console.log("pass: " + pass);

        const cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider( 'us-east-1');
        var params = {
            AuthFlow: 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
            ClientId: [myclientid],
            UserPoolId: [myuserpoolid],
            AuthParameters: {
                USERNAME: user,
                PASSWORD: pass,
            },
        };
        cognito.adminInitiateAuth(params, function(err, data) {
            if(err){
                console.log("failed to authenticate");   
                console.log(err, err.stack);
                callback(null, response);
            } else{
                console.log("successfully authenticated");
                console.log(data);
                callback(null, request);
            }
        });
    }

    else{
        callback(null, response);
    }
};
```

It doesn't seem like there's a problem with the code itself, because it works fine most of the time. But when I'm on my company's network, I keep getting prompted to enter my username and password, even if I input it correctly. I know my company's network has firewall, but I'm not sure of its settings, and how that would interfere with the authentication in the code.

After testing the code a bit more, I've discovered a few things:

1. Even with the correct credentials entered, `adminInitiateAuth` seems to give an error (so the callback to continue the request is never called). The authorization header is in the request as far as I can tell, so I'm not sure why this is happening (and only on my company's network).
2. CloudWatch logs only seem to appear when I make requests outside of my company's network.

Comment: The answer should be in the CloudWatch logs for your function.  If you don't fire the callback after adminInitiateAuth, it should not work at all because the Lambda function isn't returning anything -- which should cause CloudFront to throw a 502 error.

Comment: I don't see logs in CloudWatch half the time. The page itself doesn't get a chance to load - it just keeps prompting for a username/password. I tried commenting out the callback in adminInitiateAuth, and that's when I got a 502 error (invalid JSON) when it returned null (which means the authentication itself worked). So to me it looks like the callback calls are causing a problem, I'm just not sure how.

Comment: The logs should always be in CloudWatch, but with Lambda@Edge, you will find them in the region nearest to the edge location where the Lambda function was executed, not always us-east-1.  You can identify region for any given request adding it to the response headers: `response.headers['x-edge-region'] = [ { key: 'X-Edge-Region', value: process.env.AWS_REGION } ]`.

Comment: I tried adding the region header, and I'm getting a 502 error: "The Lambda function result failed validation: The function tried to add a blacklisted header".